# When I encrypt my home directory in Ubuntu, how does it affect programs trying to access my home directory?

Tags: command-line

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 a few weeks ago and am considering encrypting my home directory.
Excuse the fuzzy thinking but, if the directory is encrypted and I am actively using various programs, is it un-encrypted?, partially un-encrypted, or unchanged and still encrypted?

I found this on another site. Will it work OK?

```
sudo apt-get install ecrypt-utils
sudo ecryptfs-migrate-home -u USERNAME
```

Thank you,
Matthew

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think it is `ecryptfs-utils` not `ecrypt-utils` so the install line would be: 'sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils'

Answer (score 6):

After you have encrypted your home directory using the `ecryptfs-migrate-home` command, your home directory is **always encrypted**, irrespective of what *various programs you are actively using*.

You can see the encrypted files in `/home/.ecryptfs/matthew/.Private`. What you see in `/home/matthew` directory is actually the decrypted version of files present in `/home/.ecryptfs/matthew/.Private`. Note that files present in `/home/matthew` are not saved anywhere, they are just decrypted `on-the-fly`.

For example, when you try to access `/home/matthew/myfile.txt`, `ecryptfs` will look for the encrypted version of this file in `/home/.ecryptfs/matthew/.Private`, decrypt it and display the decrypted version as `/home/matthew/myfile.txt`.

Similarly, when you write to the file `/home/matthew/myfile.txt`, `ecryptfs` will encrypt the content and save it inside `/home/.ecryptfs/matthew/.Private` instead.

This is actually completely seamless and transparent to the user. You can access your home directory just like you used to before encryption.

Your files are inaccessible until you login (`/home/matthew` directory is *(almost)* empty (some files are present to make the encryption work).). However, do note that once you login, `/home/matthew` will be mounted to show the decrypted version of `/home/.ecryptfs/matthew/.Private` and **any running programs will be able to access files** available in your home directory.

I hope this clears your doubts.

P.S. Record and make a note of the key that `ecryptfs` provides after the setup procedure. In case anything bad happens (e.g., operating system crashes), without this key your files will be inaccessible.